# Can I use an aggregate function in the ORDER BY clause that was not aforedmentioned in the SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax, query-optimization, data-analysis

(for solution A) I just need someone to help confirm/deny whether the way I use an aggregate function in the ORDER BY clause is allowed, considering that I have not mentioned this specific aggregate function in the SELECT statement.

(for solution B) For further context, I was trying to find out the name of the card program with the highest transaction count. My initial version was also attached, and the primary case in point was the result of my simplification attempt. I knew the efficiency, the clarity and succinctness was obviously lacking. Any feedback on your alternative approach to the prompt, or suggestions on how to think, so that I avoid doing the following and get straight to the optimal query, would also be absolutely/highly appreciated!!

---

Given 3 tables ->
transactions: id, user_transaction_time, card_id, amount
card_programs:id, display_name
cards:id, card_program_id

Ask: Which card program has the most transactions?

Solution:

Solution A:
My final, simplified version:

```
SELECT TOP 1 card_programs.display_name AS program_name
FROM transactions T
LEFT JOIN cards ON cards.id = T.card_id
LEFT JOIN card_programs ON card_programs.id = cards.card_program_id
GROUP BY card_programs.display_name
ORDER BY COUNT(T.id) DESC
```

Solution B:
My first take:

```
WITH transaction_count_tbl AS (
SELECT card_programs.display_name AS program_name, 
card_id, 
card_programs.card_program_id, 
count(id) AS transaction_count
FROM transactions T
LEFT JOIN cards 
ON cards.id = T.card_id
LEFT JOIN card_programs
ON card_programs.id = card.card_program_id
GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY count(id) DESC
)

SELECT TOP 1 program_name
FROM transaction_count_tbl
ORDER BY transaction_count DESC
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using Postgresql?

Comment: @jarlh MySQL, my bad

Comment: But `TOP 1` is for MS SQL Server. With MySQL you'd get a syntax error.

Comment: @jarlh you are right, I was not sure about which one in the first place, because I was not solving this in any actually runnable program but as an interview prompt. Now that you mentioned it, I think it explains why I felt TOP 1 looked weird!!

Answer (score 1):

You can order by the column number starting with 1, like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 card_programs.display_name AS program_name, COUNT(T.id) AS transaction_count
FROM transactions T
LEFT JOIN cards ON cards.id = T.card_id
LEFT JOIN card_programs ON card_programs.id = cards.card_program_id
GROUP BY card_programs.display_name
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Comment: if I don't aggregate the COUNT in the leading SELECT statement (first line), only mentioned it for the first time in the ORDER BY clause, albeit still using the same GROUP BY clause - would it work? If not, is it because GROUP BY only applies to SELECT but not ORDER BY?

Comment: You can use it only in ORDER BY. Your first solution will work without any problem.